# C++, get the last modified file in a directory in windows

Tags: c++, winapi

I am building an application in `C++` that should sync a directory to server. Using the code given in [Obtaining Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/obtaining-directory-change-notifications), I wait for any change in the directory. Once a notification is given, I look for the last modified file then upload to to the server.

I can get the code of getting the last modified file by codes given in similar questions, The problem to this approach is, if the user copies 5 files of size `500 Bytes`, then all files will be copied in less than a second, so they all will have the same modification time.

I need to distinguish between them. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't the API give you the filename of the changed file?

Comment: @WeaktoEnumaElish I don't think so,I am not sure

Comment: The API does indeed tell you whcih file is modified. However, it's not a reliable API so some events can be missed. You'll need to do more. As for your specific question, you cannot distinguish between these files based on their last modified time. Further, when files are copied their meta data should be copied too. So the last modified time is not the time they were copied. It sounds like you will need to rethink everything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you recommend to do this?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation.

Comment: NTFS stores timestamps at a high resolution, even if the UI doesn't display it. I doubt you'll find they're exactly the same.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I guess I need to find a way to tell which file causes the notification

Comment: "all files will be copied in less than a second" but the timestamp of the file  is calculated in milliseconds. Can we use `GetFileTime` to get the last write time?

Comment: @DrakeWu good point. I try that. Thanks